# How to display No records found message using search pipe in angular

Tags: angular, search, pipe

I am using the below search pipe to display the set of records and appending the pipe name in HTML file.  The below pipe will get the user typed value in search bar and display the records based on the user typed input. In the below code, I am trying to search the records based on case number and patient name .This happens fine. But I am not sure how to handle No records found . When user types something in search bar, and if there are no records , I need to display a message No records found.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a variable that contains the filter pipe result and check the length of the result array .

```
<ng-container *ngIf="( nonFinalArList |  pksearch:searchNonFinalData) as result">

  <div *ngFor="let nonFinalArList of result; let i = index"> </div>

  <p *ngIf="result.length === 0">No Result</p>  

</ng-container>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-result)

[Using Pipe Results in Angular Templates](https://netbasal.com/using-pipe-results-in-angular-templates-430683fa2213)

Comment: How to apply on the searched records. I already have sort by function written. But the sorting works fine when I dont apply any search on search bar. But the sorting doesnt work on top of searched records. I have updated my question with the sort code in HTML

Comment: How can I access the result variable in ts file. If i can access the data inside the result variable in ts file, I can do sorting based on that data

Comment: You can 't access to the result variable in the ts file if you want to do the sorting in the ts file you don't need the pipe ,I don't get what you want

Comment: I have attached a image , which has search bar and a sort by functionality . Below that I have the list of records which has case no , patient name and discharge date. I am passing the JSON array to the sort by and it works fine. But the sorting dosnt work on top of searched records, because the sorting function accepts the original list ( non searched records ) as input . Now am not sure how to apply sorting (sort by date ) on top of searched records.

Comment: you have any solution for this?